# How to compare a previous DateTime with a current DateTime in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm creating a booking system, I want to make sure that users don't mistakenly select a previous date. I want the following pseudo code to be in JavaScript:

```
if(StartDateTime < Now && EndDateTime < Now)
{    
    alert("Bookings cannot be created for a previous date");
}
```

Comment: Use [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: You're _almost_ there. Let's try to write it and come back if your code doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var startDate = '5/5/2015'; // mm/dd/yyyy formate
var StartDateTime = new Date(startDate).getTime();
var endDate = '5/10/2015';
var EndDateTime = new Date(endDate).getTime();
var Now = new Date().getTime();
if(StartDateTime < Now && EndDateTime < Now){    
    alert("Bookings cannot be created for a previous date");
}
```